# function that create shared_ptr then add it to class member vector and return

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, shared-ptr

I need to create a `shared_ptr` inside function and store it inside member class vector, but also I need to return it.

for example

create Person Class

```
class Person {
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Person(std::string name) : name(std::move(name)) {}

    const std::string &getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    void setName(const std::string &name) {
        Person::name = name;
    }
};
```

then have another class that contains a vector of shared_ptr

```
class Agenda{
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Person>> people;
public:
     std::shared_ptr<Person> addPerson(const std::string& name){
        auto p = std::make_shared<Person>(name);
        people.push_back(p);
        return p;
    }
};
```

so in my `addPerson` function I need to create the `Person` and add it to my vector, but also I need to return it. what is the best way do to this?

1.
create the local `shared_ptr` push in the vector and return, I suppose this is safe because I'm returning the `shared_ptr` as value but whats happen here, I'm creating two shared_ptr? one that lives inside the vector and the other that I'm returning?, also if the user of this functions reset the returned `shared_ptr` whats happen? will affect the `shared_ptr` inside the vector?

```
 std::shared_ptr<Person> addPerson(const std::string& name){
    auto p = std::make_shared<Person>(name);
    people.push_back(p);
    return p;
}
```

2.
use `std::make_shared` inside the `push_back` then find the element inserted and then return const reference to the Person not the `shared_ptr`, whats happen here?

```
 const Person& addPerson(const std::string& name){
    people.push_back(std::make_shared<Person>(name));
    return *people.back();
}
```

3. maybe is best return a `std::weak_ptr`?

I want to know what is the best practice cons and pro to do this.

Comment: Yes method 1 creates two `shared_ptr` objects, but there's nothing wrong with that. It is a ***shared*** pointer after all. It doesn't matter how many `shared_ptr` object you have, you still only have a single `Person` object, that they all point to.

Comment: Option 2 works, as long as you don't hold the reference for longer than the lifetime of the shared pointer in the vector. But I would defintitely go for option 1 on the grounds of simplicity.

Comment: Regarding method 2, there's a simpler way than to "find" the new `Person`, if you remember that it's added *last* in the vector. You simply need to return the last element of the vector: `return *people.back();`. But remember the ownership semantics of shared pointers, they share the ownership. If you save the reference returned by method 2 and the shared pointer reference count goes to zero, the `Person` object will be destructed and the reference will become invalid.

Comment: In option 1 you have two shared pointer objects, so a reset on one won't effect the other.

Comment: Thanks guys.
so as I understand the difference between return the const Person& or the std::shared_ptr<Person> as value depends on if I want that the person returned died with the Agenda class or if the user of this function can continue having a valid person even if the agenda class died.

So if I return as std::shared_ptr<Person> this will continue existing if the instance of the agenda class died

and if I return const Person& when the instance of the agenda class died this reference is going to be invalid

is this correct?